# Access publicly shared notebook via API

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

I have a mobile app that I would like to use OneNote as the 'back end' for, serving up html from pages of a publicly shared notebook. Scouring the OneNote API, I can't find any methods to access a notebook that has been shared publicly without authorization. The app will be used by anonymous consumers, not owners of the notebooks. If I register my Application and get a Client ID, it seems all the examples expect the end user to authenticate, but the end user in the case will be anonymous, accessing notebooks that have been shared by Office 365 users. AM I headed in the wrong direction with this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the OneNote API currently does not have the functionality to get shared notebooks by app permissions

Answer (score 0):

As Manjusha mentioned, accessing notebooks anonymously isn't supported by the OneNote API (the API always works in the context of a signed in user and always requires a token to be passed in). You won't be able to get the notebook id of a public notebook with the OneNote API.

If you believe this is something the API should support, I encourage you to enter a uservoice item:
https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis